# Why storm use XOR to ensure every Bolts in topology is successfully executed. Instead of a counter

Tags: apache-storm

I am a beginner of storm. Storm's creator created a very impressive method to check every Bolts in topology, which is using XOR.
But I start wondering why he just not use a counter. When a Bolts is successfully executed, the counter will minus one. So when the counter equal with 0, means the whole task is completetly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe one can reason why counters are not only inefficient but an incorrect acker tracker mechanism in an always running topology.

- Storm tuple topology in itself can be a complex DAG. When a bolt receives ack from multiple downstream sources, what is it to do with the counters? Should it increment them, should it always decrement them? In what order?
- Storm tuples have **random message Ids**. Counters will be finite. A topology runs forever emitting billions of tuples. How will you map the 673686557th tuple to a counter id? With XOR, you only have a single state to maintain and broadcast.
- XOR operations are hardware instructions that **execute extremely efficiently**. Counters are longs which require huge amounts of storage. They have overflow problems and defeat the original requirement of a solution with a low space overhead.